# Static class dll records stored in Dictionary available to different projects or only for seperate project

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dll, static

I understand that we can access static class in same project .

In my scenario, suppose I have one common dll with static class, that class contain one dictionary.

```
 private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> **SettingsCache** = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

If I have 2 other projects, which contain above dll, then while I have adding data in that dictionary will be available to second project?

Means suppose in Proj1 I called that function which add 2 records in that dictionary.

```
  public IDictionary<string, string> AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> settingsCollection = null;
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var declaringType = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
            if ((declaringType != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(declaringType.Namespace)) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_callingHandler))
            {
                string handler = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_callingHandler) ? _callingHandler : declaringType.Namespace;
                    if (!SettingsCache.ContainsKey(handler))
                    {
                        var settings = GetSettingsForHandler(handler);
                        **SettingsCache.TryAdd(handler, settings);**
                    }
                settingsCollection = SettingsCache[handler] as Dictionary<string, string>;
            }
            return settingsCollection;
        }
    }
enter code here
```

So whatever records added from Proj1 call to APPSetting function will available to proj2 dll?
Then will those records  available to second project's dll?

Comment: It'd be nice if down-voters posted a reason for down-voting a question.

Comment: @AshwinNair Yes. I also like to hear reason for same.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be shared only for the current AppDomain.

In other words, if you have an application - the entire application will share that dictionary, regardless of what library the code is in.

If you run two *instances* of the application, they will not share the information.

Things are a bit more complicated for ASP.NET applications. Your site will share the dictionary, however there is no guarantee as to the lifetime of the variable - the application may  be recycled at any time, at which point the variable is destroyed and recreated.